# Angular js ng-options not able to set the value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have started playing around with angular js and here is the problem with `ng-option`.

I have a below DOM structure, where i have used `ng-option` inside `ng-repeat`. And i'm declaring Main model in `ng-init`

```
<div ng-init='Mainmodel="{"SelectedValue": "value1",
    "dummy" : [
     {
          "name" : "first attribute",
          "description" : "attribute first description",
          "values" : [{"id":"value1", "Name":"name1"}, {"id":"value2", "Name":"name2"}]
     },
     {
          "name" : "second attribute",
          "description" : "attribute second description",
         "values" : [{"id":"value1", "Name":"name1"}, {"id":"value2", "Name":"name2"}]
     }
    ]" >

<div ng-repeat="model in Mainmodel">
    <select ng-model="SelectedValue" ng-options="item.id as item.Name for item in Mainmodel.dummy.values">
    <option value=""> Please select </option>
</div>

</div>
```

The problem is, even thought the model `SelectedValue` is set to `value1` the dropdwon is not selecting the model value. Dropdown is selected with `Please select` .

Can any one please tell where i'm doing wrong. As per my knowledge dropdwon will be selected with `ng-model` value.

Note : The above model structure is not accurate. Model is Valid dropdown is loading with all values.

Comment: Your object is invalid...that array has no key `{key:val, []}` isn't valid

Comment: i don't have the exact model. i tried to create a replica of it. But actually the model is valid

Comment: You should probably post the exact model.

Comment: i don't have it now. i will update soon

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `ng-options`. You are using `item.id as item.Name for item in Mainmodel.values` but `item` does not have a property `id` or `Name`. It has `name`, `description` and `values`. You need to iterate over the items in `values`.

You'll need to work around this probably using a combination of `ng-repeat` over `ng-repeat` without `ng-options`.

Something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="model in Mainmodel">
    <select ng-model="SelectedValue">
    <option value="">Make a choice</option>
    <div ng-repeat="item in Mainmodel.values">
    <option ng-repeat="subitem in item.values" value="{{subitem.id}}">{{subitem.Name}}</option>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am writing this from top of my mind. I have not tested, only trying to give you an idea.

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake(typo), i have updated the model and ng-option. Please see.

Comment: not a lot changes. You still have to go through `dummy.values`. This is your collection over which you need to iterate to populate the dropdown list. That is also the reason why your `SelectedValue` is not selecting anything.